# Login screen returns after entering login and password

Tags: raspbian, boot, ssh, gui, login

I've just installed tightVNC on my raspberry pi. After I rebooted the device, it showed the login screen, which usually doesn't appear. When I enter the login, there's a black screen with a blinking underscore for about three seconds, after that it returns to the login screen. The login is definitely not wrong, if I type in a wrong password it shows an error message.

So I booted to the command line and removed tightvncserver. Still, I can't login. If the raspberry doesn't boot to the GUI I can easily login with user pi, but with the GUI login screen the same doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: I am in the same situation. Could you solve it? I installed tightvncserver an the problem appears. Now I removed it and the situation persist.

Answer (score 2):

Think this is the same issue I had after installing tightvnc. You need to make the *pi* user the owner of .Xauthority and that should fix the login issue. At least it did for me.

```
chown pi:pi .Xauthority
```

Comment: had to prefix with ```sudo``` for me, but worked well